# Implementation of Ford Fulkerson Algorithm with incremental updates

Tags: algorithm, network-flow, ford-fulkerson

I have implemented Ford Fulkerson algorithm and now trying to work on a variant of it.

Lets say the given graph with its solution is
[image]

Supposing that after the solution is derived, capacity of one of the edges increases or decreases. We need to find an algorithm to get the new max Flow **using the current solution and NOT from the start.**

My suggestion is that, for this example, if we assume the capacity of 1-3 edge reduces from 12 to 8, then we need to do a BFS from 1 to start node and reduce the flow on each of the edges by 4 AND do a BFS from 3 to 5 and reduce the flow there also. But I am not sure if this is correct. Even if its correct, I am not getting an idea of how can I implement this?

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach is correct.

Use the same BFS you used to find the max Flow.

Keep in mind that:

- you can't use the edge you're adjusting.
- The edge might not be fully utilized so you may need to push back only a smaller amount of flow.

Comment: Can you help me with a pseudo code for this implementation?